# how can I refactor my code to ensure there is no repitition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will be calling three different endpoints in a project I am working on. The functions handling the requests are all the same apart from the different urls I will be calling. Below is an example of my code

```
const handleSubmitPhoneNumber = (e, next) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const payload = {
            "phone": user.phone
        }
        const postPhoneNumber = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            await axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload)
                .then(response => {
                    setLoading(false)
                    console.log(response)
                    let res = response;
                    if (res.data.id === 11) {
                        next();
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        }
        postPhoneNumber();
    }

    const handleSubmitVerificationCode = (e, next) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const payload = {
            "verificationCode": user.verificationCode
        }
        const postVerificationCode = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            await axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload)
                .then(response => {
                    setLoading(false)
                    console.log(response)
                    let res = response;
                    if (res.data.id === 11) {
                        next();
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
        postVerificationCode();
    }
```

how can I write this code to avoid repetition since everything is the same apart from the base urls.

Comment: You could move axios.post part to an async function with a callback of `if (res.data.id === 11) next()`

Answer (score 1):

Make a function just for your post requrest:

```js
async function POST(url, payload, next) {
  setLoading(true)
  await axios.post(url, payload)
    .then(response => {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(response)
      let res = response;
      if (res.data.id === 11) {
        next();
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Then you can just use this function in your code like this:

```js
const handleSubmitPhoneNumber = (e, next) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const payload = {
        "phone": user.phone
    }
    POST("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload, next)

const handleSubmitVerificationCode = (e, next) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const payload = {
        "verificationCode": user.verificationCode
    }
    POST("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload, next)
}
```

Comment: Depending on where the async function is defined, `next` may need to be passed.

Comment: Yes `next` can be passed in as parameter.Will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
const handleSubmitPhoneNumber = (e, next) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const payload = {
        "phone": user.phone
    }
    postMethod("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload, next);
}

const handleSubmitVerificationCode = (e, next) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const payload = {
        "verificationCode": user.verificationCode
    }
    postMethod("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", payload, next);
}

const postMethod = async (url, payload, next) => {
    setLoading(true)
    await axios.post(url, payload)
        .then(response => {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(response)
            let res = response;
            if (res.data.id === 11) {
                next();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Comment: `next()` may need to be bound depending on where and what next is.

Comment: According to your code it's a method. May have a logic inside? What exactly you need to do inside that ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: Inside next function what are you planning to do? Display a message in UI, change route etc ?

Comment: I am not OP. The OP is @Raphael

Comment: @Faraz: `next` is a function supplied as an argument and called without any binding in the original.  Why would it need binding in these refactorings?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I missed that he passed it in. Sorry.

Comment: @JanithWidarshana Disregard my comment about binding `next` i was mistaken, sorry

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner version of the idea expressed in the other answers might look like this:

```js
const postMethod = (url, getPayload) => async (e, next) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true)
    await axios.post(url, getPayload())
        .then(response => {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(response)
            let res = response;
            if (res.data.id === 11) {
                next();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

const handleSubmitPhoneNumber = postMethod (
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  () => {phone: user.phone}
)

const handleSubmitVerificationCode = postMethod (
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  () => {verificationCode: user.verificationCode}
)
```

The main reason I like this better is that the handling of `e` and `next` doesn't vary between these handlers, so ideally it belongs in the common code.

I'm not happy though, in this or in the original, with the global access to `user`.  Could this also be passed as a parameter?